# Memory issues with HTTParty and download large files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, memory, httparty

Is this going to cause memory issues with Ruby. I know Open-URI writes to a TempFile if the size goes over 10KB. But will HTTParty try and save the whole PDF to memory before it writes to TempFile?

```
src = Tempfile.new("file.pdf")
src.binmode
src.write HTTParty.get("large_file.pdf").parsed_response
```

Comment: HTTParty was not intended for downloading PDFs. It's an API client designed for small XML or JSON exchanges.

Comment: What's wrong with Open-URI? An alternative using Net::HTTP is in my answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Net::HTTP. See [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) (in particular the section titled "Streaming Response Bodies").

Here's the example from the docs:

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/large_file')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri

  http.request request do |response|
    open 'large_file', 'w' do |io|
      response.read_body do |chunk|
        io.write chunk
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome! Somewhat related question but how are you doing this for your large file uploads?

Comment: It's also might be better if you open file for writing in binary mode, simply add `b` flag, like: `open(filename, 'wb') { |io| ... }`.

Comment: Didn't debug it deeply but seems like it downloads "in background" while program runs further.